# c# XML avoid html encode using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

After creating an xml file using XDocument I end up with:

```
&lt;![CDATA[text]]&gt;
```

and

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

But I want to keep these as HTML, how do I stop this?

Comment: A curious mix of XML and HTML, in both code and text.

Comment: Nothing I can do about it, the data contains the html in the string.  I wasn't aware of the new XCData() option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are passing a string to an XDocument or XElement constructor somewhere, where that string contains XML. Don't. Instead, use `XDocument.Parse(string)` or `XElement.Parse(string)`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx

Note that this will only work for HTML that happens to be well-formed XML, obviously.

For example:

```
XElement.Parse("<TagName>The string has <br /> in it.</TagName>")
```

If you statically know the text, just build it up using constructor calls, e.g.

```
new XElement("TagName", "The string has ", new XElement("br"), " in it.")
```

Comment: I actually found that using:

    new XElement(elementName, new XCData(value));

Resolves the CData issue, so instead of using Parse is there a simple add method for a line break in XDocument that adds the tag <w:br/>?

Comment: sure, Add(new XElement("br")) or the overload with a namespace

Comment: Sorry you've slightly confused me, let's say I create an element like so:
  new XElement("TagName","The string has <br /> in it");
  How would I replace the <br />? surely not with just br?

Comment: Doesn't like: new XElement.Parse? Do I have to write as: new XElement(XElement.Parse(etc?

Comment: Either use `new XElement(...)`, either `XElement.Parse(...)` without the `new`.